# How to group-by to get MultiPoint/GeometryCollection in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, spatial, geometry

I have a table x like this:

Columns:

```
SubjectID int(11)
Timestamp bigint(20) 
fix_geom point
```

[image]

When i try to group my fix_geom column to a MultiPoint (or GeometryCollection) by SubjectID, like:

```
SELECT SubjectID, ST_AsText(MultiPoint(fix_geom))
FROM x
WHERE SubjectID = 100
GROUP BY SubjectID;
```

i get a table with a multipoint geometry, but it contains just one single Point instead of the many i'd liked to see there...:

[image]

Can anybody tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Cheers and many thanks in advance,
Olaf

Answer (score 1):

As [Evan Carroll](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2639/evan-carroll) said in a comment: Unlike PostGIS, spatial aggregates are not available for MySQL.

The workaround left in a comment by [danblack](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/158002/danblack) works:

> It looks like you want `MultiPoint` to be an [aggregate function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html), which is isn't. You'll probably need something like `ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT('MultiPoint(', GROUP_CONCAT(...), ')'))`, where `...` gets an `X Y` string from `fix_geom`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use aggregate function `ST_Collect()` since MySQL **8.0.24**.

It supports `DISTINCT` and `OVER` clause, and generates automagically a `MULTIPOINT` :

```
SELECT ALL
    SubjectID,
    ST_Collect(fix_geom),
    ST_AsText(ST_Collect(fix_geom)) -- MULTIPOINT((...),(...),...)
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY 1
```

If you store points separately and/or need a GeoJSON :

```
SELECT ALL
    SubjectID,
    ST_Collect(Point(latitude, longitude)),
    ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Collect(Point(latitude, longitude))) -- {"type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [...]}
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY 1
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-aggregate-functions.html